# Adding border to canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing some arrows in canvas (similar arrows can be viewed in a life cycle). I want to draw border to all these arrows individually just like we add to divs. I tried using stroke style and stroke method but it filled my entire arrow.

I am using fill style and fill to fill color to my arrows.

Is there any way to do it? Is it like fill and stroke methods can never be used together?

Comment: Could you give us some code? It should be possible to use a stroke and a fill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use beginPath() and closePath() on your canvas's context ("ctx" down here), followed by a fill() to actually fill the element:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(170, 80);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.lineTo(100,150);
ctx.lineTo(170, 80);
// Etc, Make your movements to draw the arrow, here.
ctx.closePath();

//Line settings and drawing
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();

//Fill settings and drawing
ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
ctx.fill();
```